# python loop thru nested dictionary obtain keys only based on keyword

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary and I am trying to figure out a way to loop through keys to obtain key values only.

```
VAV_SENSOR_NAME_MAP = {

    'ZN-T': {'A' : 'zone', 'B' : 'air', 'C' : 'temp', 'D' : 'sensor'},
    'Space Temperature Local': {'A' : 'zone', 'B' : 'air', 'C' : 'temp', 'D' : 'sensor'},
    
    'ZN-SP': {'A' : 'zone', 'B' : 'air', 'C' : 'temp', 'D' : 'effective', 'E' : 'sp'},
    'Space Temperature Setpoint Active': {'A' : 'zone', 'B' : 'air', 'C' : 'temp', 'D' : 'effective', 'E' : 'sp'},
    
    'DA-T': {'A' : 'discharge', 'B' : 'air', 'C' : 'temp', 'D' : 'sensor'},
    'Discharge Air Temperature': {'A' : 'discharge', 'B' : 'air', 'C' : 'temp', 'D' : 'sensor'},
    
    'SA-F': {'A' : 'air', 'B' : 'flow', 'C' : 'sensor'},
    'Discharge Air Flow': {'A' : 'air', 'B' : 'flow', 'C' : 'sensor'},
    
    'HTG-O': {'A' : 'reheat', 'B' : 'cmd'},
    'Heating Valve Command': {'A' : 'reheat', 'B' : 'cmd'},
    
    'DPR-O': {'A' : 'air', 'B' : 'damper', 'B' : 'cmd'},
    'Actual Air Valve Position': {'A' : 'air', 'B' : 'damper', 'B' : 'cmd'},
    
}
```

For example how could I create function to print/obtain key values for `ZN-T` only? Hoping to ***only*** obtain only the key values of `zone` `air` `temp` `sensor`

trying to make up a function:

```
def get_all_values(nested_dictionary,key_word):
    #print(key_word)
    for key, value in nested_dictionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            get_all_values(value,key_word)
        else:
            print(value[key_word]) 
            
get_all_values(VAV_SENSOR_NAME_MAP,'ZN-T')
```

This will give me a `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Any tips greatly appreciated

Comment: can just get the values in a list like `list(VAV_SENSOR_NAME_MAP['ZN-T'].values())`

Comment: wow thats easy if you post and answer ill hit the green Checkbox thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the values of the inner dict by selecting the dict by key then calling the values method on it.

```py
VAV_SENSOR_NAME_MAP = {

    'ZN-T': {'A': 'zone', 'B': 'air', 'C': 'temp', 'D': 'sensor'},
    'Space Temperature Local': {'A': 'zone', 'B': 'air', 'C': 'temp', 'D': 'sensor'},

    'ZN-SP': {'A': 'zone', 'B': 'air', 'C': 'temp', 'D': 'effective', 'E': 'sp'},
    'Space Temperature Setpoint Active': {'A': 'zone', 'B': 'air', 'C': 'temp', 'D': 'effective', 'E': 'sp'},

    'DA-T': {'A': 'discharge', 'B': 'air', 'C': 'temp', 'D': 'sensor'},
    'Discharge Air Temperature': {'A': 'discharge', 'B': 'air', 'C': 'temp', 'D': 'sensor'},

    'SA-F': {'A': 'air', 'B': 'flow', 'C': 'sensor'},
    'Discharge Air Flow': {'A': 'air', 'B': 'flow', 'C': 'sensor'},

    'HTG-O': {'A': 'reheat', 'B': 'cmd'},
    'Heating Valve Command': {'A': 'reheat', 'B': 'cmd'},

    'DPR-O': {'A': 'air', 'B': 'damper', 'B': 'cmd'},
    'Actual Air Valve Position': {'A': 'air', 'B': 'damper', 'B': 'cmd'},

}

print(list(VAV_SENSOR_NAME_MAP['ZN-T'].values()))
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
['zone', 'air', 'temp', 'sensor']
```